# HTTP request to obtain HTTP status code, but no content

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, axios

I'm using [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) to get the http status for URLs:

```js
async function getUrlHttpStatus (url) {
  try {
    const res = await axios({ method: 'get', url })
    return {
      status: res.status,
      statusText: res.statusText
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return {
      status: err.response.status,
      statusText: err.response.statusText
    }
  }
}
```

This obviously brings back all the content from that URL as well, and if there is a lot, it can be very slow.

Is there a way to make a HTTP request, to get the HTTP status code, without downloading all the content from the URL, so it's quick..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use the [HEAD](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD) method, which per definition returns just the Head (i.e. Status code) and no body.

Answer (score 0):

The way you access error is : `err.response.data.your_attribute_from_the_server`

If the message from the server is in the the error object is in the `message` `attribute`
Eg : `err.response.data.message`

```
async function getUrlHttpStatus (url) {
  try {
    const res = await axios({ method: 'get', url })
    return {
      status: res.status,
      statusText: res.statusText
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return {
      status: err.response.status,
      statusText: err.response.data.message//here replace the message attibute with whatever attribute you've sent from the server
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually want the `statusText` though, not the error message. Like "Not found" for 404 errors.